# How to keep a YouTube playlist synced to a local folder as mp3 files?

Tags: sync, youtube, youtube-dl

Is it possible to keep a public YouTube playlist synced to a local folder as mp3 files?

Key characteristics:

- Add mp3 file to local folder, if new video is added to the playlist
- Delete mp3 file in local folder, if respective video is removed from the playlist

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [this](https://github.com/borysn/sync-youtube-playlist) GitHub repo, which seems to do exactly what you want.
Or you can use plain `youtube-dl` with `--download-archive`, as seen in youtube-dl's man page, although this will not remove any videos:

> How do I download only new videos from a playlist?
>
> Use download-archive feature. With this feature you should initially download the complete playlist with `--download-archive path/to/download/archive/file.txt` that will record identifiers of all the videos in a special file.  Each subsequent run with the same `--download-archive` will download only new videos and skip all videos that have been downloaded before.  Note that only successful downloads are recorded in the file.
>
> For example, at first,
> `youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re"`
> will download the complete PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re playlist and create a file archive.txt.  Each subsequent run will only download new videos if any:
> `youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re"`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a direct answer, but if you are ok with occasionally re-downloading some of the older playlist files you can set up a cronjob to find and delete files in a target directory using `find`.

You should review the playlist and estimate how long files usually stay on it before disappearing, and use that number of days for your variable. Here in my example I chose 30 days.

Here's an example Bash script for cron to run as an @daily job:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Delete all files in a directory older than 30 days
# (careful, this is recursive and will delete files in subdirectories)
find /PATH/TO/youtube-dl-playlist-files -mtime +30 -delete
```

Any files still on the playlist but older than 30 days will be deleted, and youtube-dl will re-download them when you run it next. This isn't optimal but it may be good enough.